# Android main thread click event not respondning

Tags: android

I have on/off buttons. When on is clicked the algorithm starts working (works about 10 seconds).

The algorithm is working in another thread (not in main). I want to stop the algorithm using off button, but it isn't handle the click event...

But there is something strange.

When I use this kind of code block when on is clicked it is ok.

```
while(true){
                    //do something
}
```

My algorithm is something like this

```
 myObj.startAlg();
```

Comment: that is too less of Your code to say anything about it. Please post more of the relevant part, where Your button click is fired and the method that is firing.

Comment: Do you use Thread.sleep() in the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

Cancel the task, when the button is pressed with:

```
AsynTask.cancel(true);
```

In the AsyncClass add the `if(isCancelled())` part, like this:
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

```
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          // you need to break your loop on particular condition here

             if(isCancelled())
                  break;      
             /*Put this in the doInBackgound() for the purpose*/
         }
         return totalSize;
     }
```

**EDIT:**

And to add more information form the documentation of AsyncTask:

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean).
>   Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to
>   return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead
>   of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after
>   doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled
>   as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible
>   (inside a loop for instance.)

Comment: I can't handle the clicked event !
How can I cancel task ?

Comment: Well can you not put a `OnClickListener` to that button or put in the XML of it `android:onClick="startCancelAsyncTask"`. That `startCancelAsyncTask()` function should be of type void and in it you can handle the click event.

Comment: it is in xml ...
but it isn't responding

Comment: Please paste the XML and the function, if also possible - the AsyncClass with its methods as well.